# Spring MVC "redirect:" prefix always redirects to http -- how do I make it stay on https?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I solved this myself, but I spent so long discovering such a simple solution, I figured it deserved to be documented here.

I have a typical Spring 3 MVC setup with an InternalResourceViewResolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

I have a pretty simple handler method in my controller, but I've simplified it even more for this example:

```
@RequestMapping("/groups")
public String selectGroup() {
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

The problem is, if I browse to `https://my.domain.com/groups`, I end up at `http://my.domain.com/` after the redirect.  (In actuality my load-balancer redirects all http requests to https, but this just causes multiple browser alerts of the type "You are leaving/entering a secure connection" for folks who have such alerts turned on.)

So the question is: how does one get spring to redirect to https when that's what the original request used?

Comment: What about just using "redirect:". Using a relative url after the redirect should work as well.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The short answer is, set the InternalResourceViewResolver's redirectHttp10Compatible property to false:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  <property name="redirectHttp10Compatible" value="false" />
</bean>
```

You could do this on a per-request basis instead, by having your handler method return View instead of String, and creating the RedirectView yourself, and calling `setHttp10Compatible(false)`.

(It turns out the culprit is HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect, which the RedirectView uses for HTTP 1.0 compatible redirects, but not otherwise.  I guess this means it's dependent on your servlet container's implementation (?); I observed the problem in both Tomcat and Jetty.)

Comment: This also worked for me, in a Spring Boot @Configuration class i simply did `this.thymeleafViewResolver.setRedirectHttp10Compatible(false);`. I had the tomcat headers in my application.properties file already, I also need them, but they didn't do trick. Now my app returns 303s with a relative URL instead of 302s with an absolute URL. I'm om spring boot 1.5.14 with spring 4, maybe this behaviour changed with newer versions?

Comment: Two years later and i stumble over the same answer again - and it saved my ass again. We badly need an option to upvote twice...

Answer (score 43):

Spring Boot provides [this nice configuration based solution](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-enable-https) to this if you're running behind a proxy server, simply add these two properties to your `application.properties` file:

```java
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
```

This works for me deploying the otherwise unchanged [spring-boot-sample-web-ui](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-ui) to Elastic Beanstalk behind an https load balancer. Without these properties the redirect on line 68 of the `MessageController` defaults to http and hangs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution if your use case is User -- LoadBalancer -- Application!

Comment: How do you give more than one upvote? This is definitely the right anwer!

Comment: Thanks. This helped my app that was behind a load balancer. The config params have changed slightly. server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto

Comment: None of these worked for me but a solution from Albert Bos did.  Adding the line `server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects=true` works currently

Comment: Spent so many hours to debug this issue.. Thank you so much , this resolved my issues!

Comment: I don't find these properties in spring-boot 2.4.x documentation.  Perhaps they are not supported anymore.  But I find `server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects` suggested by @albert-bos.  See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.9/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me is adding this to application.properties `server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects=true`

So when you have:

```
public function redirect() {
  return "redirect:/"
}
```

Without the `server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects` it will add a `Location` header like: `http://my-host.com/`.
With the `server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects` it will look like: `/`.
So it will be relative to the current page from browser perspective.

Comment: I believe this setting only exists in Spring Boot version >= 2.X but good to know.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure?

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.java) it seems there is no difference. Both variants use the encoded url, see the `sendRedirect` method in RedirectView:

```
String encodedURL = isRemoteHost(targetUrl) ? targetUrl : response.encodeRedirectURL(targetUrl);
if (http10Compatible) {
    // Other if/else stuff depending on status code
    
    // Send status code 302 by default.
    response.sendRedirect(encodedURL);
}
else {
    HttpStatus statusCode = getHttp11StatusCode(request, response, targetUrl);
    response.setStatus(statusCode.value());
    response.setHeader("Location", encodedURL);
}
```

I had the same problem, but it was triggered by setting up tomcat behind a loadbalancer. The loadbalancer does the SSL handshake and forwards to tomcat a plain http connection.

Solution would be to send a special Http Header in your Loadbalancer, so tomcat can "trust" this connection. Using a servlet filter should set response.isSecure flag. Then overwrite RedirectView to see if response.isSecure and handle it the right way.

I kept this solution short because i am not sure if it machtes the question.

Comment: I imagine that response.encodeRedirectURL doesn't touch the protocol, and that it's response.sendRedirect that is setting the protocol to http.  Your solution would probably work, but mine is easier (at the cost of HTTP/1.0 compatibility, of course).

Answer (score 4):

Since Spring Boot 2.1 you have to add the following configuration to your `application.properties`:

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

or `application.yml`:

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
```

Comment: This works for deployments using jetty. Thank you!

Comment: Since 2.2 that property is deprecated, you should use `server.forward-headers-strategy` now. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126518/) more about that property.

Comment: thanks for the comment above, this `server.forward-headers-strategy=native` fixed my problem, i'm with jetty too.

Answer (score 0):

if you use springmvc ,you can try the following:

```
modelAndView.setView(new RedirectView("redirect url path", true, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

I add `scheme="https"` in file server.xml for connector with `port="80"`:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" scheme="https" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This started happening for us on Chrome 87 (https://blog.chromium.org/2020/08/protecting-google-chrome-users-from.html), for a quickfix to avoid the warning page in our springboot app we solve it by adding `use-relative-redirects: true` in the `application.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue...When redirecting it goes to http instead of HTTPS , below changes done :

```
RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView("/xyz",true);
redirect.setExposeModelAttributes(false);
redirect.setHttp10Compatible(false);
mav = new ModelAndView(redirect);
```