# Spring security switching to http after login. How can I keep https?

Tags: spring, redirect, https, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC and Spring Security. My redirects were switching https to http until I found this post. [Spring MVC "redirect:" prefix always redirects to http -- how do I make it stay on https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401113/spring-mvc-redirect-prefix-always-redirects-to-http-how-do-i-make-it-stay-o). I also had to set the redirectHttp10Compatible property to false in my AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver.

The problem is that https still switches to http after login. Once I am logged in I can set my app back to https in the address bar and it will stick. Also, I am using IP authentication for most users in which case https stays thanks to the solution above.

I am trying to add redirectHtp10Compatible to login_security_check or something like that but am stuck. Here my security-config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<http auto-config='true' access-denied-page="/login">
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/styles/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/scripts/**" filters="none" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/error/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/ajaxTimeOut" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/checkSystem" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/adminUser/**" access="ROLE_SSADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <form-login login-page="/ajaxTimeOut" login-processing-url="/login_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="ipPreAuthFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="ipAuthDetailsSource" class="com.mydomain.security.IPBasedPreAuthenticatedDetailsSource" />

<beans:bean id="ipPreAuthFilter" class="com.mydomain.security.IPPreAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="preAuthManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationDetailsSource" ref="ipAuthDetailsSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="preAuthProvider"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="preAuthUserService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthUserService" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" >
            <salt-source user-property="salt" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userService" class="com.mydomain.security.UserServiceImpl" />
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="com.mydomain.security.PasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="256" />
</beans:bean>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include all the relevant Spring Security configuration and let us know what version of Spring Security you are using.

Comment: @Marc One question: how is the login page invoked: directly by the user (he enters http(s)://.../login)? or by intercepting a request to a prtected url (the user requests http(s)://.../adminUser/,,,)?, Second question: does the user do this via http or https?

Comment: If the user is not IP authenticated they will be redirected to the login page. If they are IP authenticated they will go to the requested page or the home page. The user can use http or https and I need the app to stay on whichever protocol they come to the site with.

Answer (score -1):

Add the **requires-channel** attribute to your secure urls in the **intercep-url** nodes

just like this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https" />
```