# Spring redirect: using HTTPS with code based configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app deployed on a web server I have a controller annotated `@Controller` that does a redirect by returning `redirect:/home` this redirect changes the `https` to `http` I already saw an answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401157/5038073) but I'm totally unfamiliar with XML based configuration and want to know if there's a way I can configure the bean from the code and not using XML.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaConfig to set the `redirectHttp10Compatible` property to `false` to prevent this.

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver configureViewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver vr = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  vr.setRedirectHttp10Compatible(false);
  // other options
  return vr;
}
```

As per [`InternalResourceViewResolver.setRedirectHttp10Compatible()` docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html#setRedirectHttp10Compatible-boolean-):

> Set whether redirects should stay compatible with HTTP 1.0 clients.

Comment: Thanks will try it. Do I have to set the suffix? because I'm not using jsp, or should i just set it to .html?

Comment: I removed other options from the example, this depends on your setup. You can see how `InternalResourceViewResolver` is configured currently in your context and then carry forward the current config.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the application is behind Ngnix.  HTTPS is managed by Ngnix and the app uses HTTP only. A little change in Ngnix configuration solved the problem: I added this line in each `location` block:

```
proxy_redirect ~^http:(.*)$ https:$1;
```